# TRAC XMLRPC Plugin fails to retrieve tickets, even though debug log shows results from Trac[query]

Tags: trac

I have a functioning python script that will pull all sorts of information from TRAC XMLRPC except a ticket.query. From the debug log I can see that the query comes in and is processed and finds four (4) tickets; however the return is empty.

I have replaced the ServerProxy site with http://trac-hacks.org/rpc, and it works.

Configuration:

```
    Trac 1.0.1
    Apache 2.2
    XMLPRC plugin 1.1.5
    Python 2.7.6
    Active Directory
```

Code:

```
    from xmlrpclib import *
    p = ServerProxy('http://user:password@host/trac/project/login/xmlrpc')
    print p.system.getAPIVersion()
    print p.ticket.query("max=0&status!=closed")
```

Return:

```
    [1, 1, 5]
    []
```

Debug Log:

```
    2016-07-07 07:46:42,240 Trac[web_ui] DEBUG: RPC incoming request of content type 'text/xml' dispatched to <tracrpc.xml_rpc.XmlRpcProtocol object at 0x03D3E630>
    2016-07-07 07:46:42,240 Trac[web_ui] DEBUG: RPC(XML-RPC) call by 'user'
    2016-07-07 07:46:42,240 Trac[xml_rpc] DEBUG: RPC(xml) call by 'user', method 'ticket.query' with args: ('max=0&status!=closed',)
    2016-07-07 07:46:42,240 Trac[web_ui] DEBUG: RPC(XML-RPC) call by 'user' ticket.query
    2016-07-07 07:46:42,240 Trac[query] DEBUG: Count results in Query: 4
    2016-07-07 07:46:42,240 Trac[xml_rpc] DEBUG: RPC(xml) 'ticket.query' result: []
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `max=0` from the query? According to the documentation `max=0` should work, but I'd verify.

Comment: Yes I have, the symptoms are the same.  Additionally, I have found that when I execute `p.system.methodHelp("ticket.query")` I receive  the following fault: `Fault: <Fault 1: "'sequence item 2: expected string, NoneType found' while executing 'system.methodHelp()'">`